# Power to fuel pump drops on engine crank

Tags: electrical, fuel-system, golf

I have a Mk1 Golf with the injected engine. I have not been able to get the car to start due to no fuel reaching the engine. I have tested the fuel pump with a multimeter and have noticed the volts drop from around 10v to 0 when cranking the engine.

- Relays seem ok - I can feel them click on and off.
- Fuse is ok
- Pump is working ok (tested it outside of the car with direct connection to battery)

Would anyone know what could be causing this or what I should be looking for?

Comment: Just because the relay clicks doesn't mean it's making contact or passing electricity. You need to verify it's good. The easiest thing to do is to change it out with a known good one in the fuse panel. Also, only 10v? That seems to be an issue in and of itself. It should be seeing full battery voltage. Have you checked your battery to ensure it's up to snuff? Should be over 12.5vdc (at least).

Comment: Also verify a) that the big-wire connections between the battery, ground, and starter are in good shape (disconnect, clean, and reassemble each of them), b) that the battery itself is good (have the battery load-tested), and c) that the battery is fully charged (if it isn't fully charged, there's something wrong with the charging system).

Comment: @paulster2 I should mention that 10v is with just the battery - car not running, obviously. I am (was) getting 12.5 at the alternator when I lasted tested about 12 months ago.